# on click function affects multiple elements with same class name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I want to auto play youtube video on my video style page i.e http://picovico.com/video-styles/. I could auto play the video by clicking on my image thumbnail with bellow given code. However this affects other elements with same class in the page. My code is:

```
jQuery( function($) {    
 $('.cq-expandgrid-toggle').on('click', function(ev) {
    $("#pvideo")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault(); 
  });
});
```

How could I achieve it. I am little bit confused about "this" object.

Comment: I'd recommend also posting the HTML that is being queried in your question as opposed to linking to it externally, along with posting both the HTML/Javascript in a code snippet.

Comment: Well, that's what `$('.cq-expandgrid-toggle')` does.  It selects all matching elements, so all elements with that class.  If you want to target only a specific element (or more specific set of elements), you'd need a more specific selector.

Comment: I think using `this` would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the `eq(index)` to select the first node which class name is `.cq-expandgrid-toggle`. And, the `id` selector is unique in one page, so it's unnecessary add [0] for it. sorry my English, i hope you can understand what i meant

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.cq-expandgrid-toggle').eq(0).on('click', function(ev) {
        $("#pvideo").src += "&autoplay=1";
        ev.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the scope of your jQuery selector to elements inside the clicked div tag.

This should work.

```
jQuery('.cq-expandgrid-toggle').click(function(ev) { 
    jQuery(this).parent().find("iframe")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

**Update**

When user clicks on second video when first video is playing, the first video also starts playing along with second video as first video also has `autoplay=1`. You need to reset the first iframe's url before adding `autoplay=1` to the second iframe.

```
var url = jQuery('#YourIFrameID').attr('src').replace('&autoplay=1', '');
jQuery('#YourIFrameID').setAttribute('src', '');
jQuery('#YourIFrameID').setAttribute('src', url);
```

Also you have set id of each iframe as `pvideo` which is wrong HTML as ids should be unique.

If you ask me the way you have implemented this video gallery is totally wrong.
There are a bunch of issues

1. You are loading all the iframes on page load. You should have used [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to load the player on thumbnail click.
2. Loading all the iframes on page load takes a lot of time. Most users will not play all your videos.
3. Also when you append `autoplay=1` the iframe loads again anyway so loading on page load is a waste.

YouTube API also provides you `stopVideo` and `playVideo` methods to stop and start the videos. So on thumbnail click you can stop the current video, load new video and play it.

Comment: I tried both find("iframe") and find("pvideo"). Both way the elements are affecting each other.  pvideo is the id I have used in the embedded iframe.

Answer (score -1):

I used some pseudo code to test this,

HTML

```
<div class="cq-expandgrid-toggle">
  <span id="pvideo">
      Click me
  </span>
</div>


<div class="cq-expandgrid-toggle">
  <span id="pvideo">
      Click me
  </span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JQuery

```
jQuery( function($) {    
 $('.cq-expandgrid-toggle').on('click', function(ev) {
     var pvideo = this.querySelector("#pvideo");
     pvideo.innerHTML = "You clicked on me"; 
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/flyinggambit/LcbLb386/

So you should change your code to,

```
jQuery( function($) {    
 $('.cq-expandgrid-toggle').on('click', function(ev) {
    var pvideo = this.querySelector("#pvideo");
    pvideo.src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault(); 
  });
});
```

I am not sure if there is a better way to write this `this.querySelector("#pvideo");` in JQuery.

**Update:**

Now that I have a fair idea of your HTML code, 
I tried the below code, there are some modifications that you should do to your HTML code to make things easier.

- Make sure `cq-expandgrid-toggle` and `cq-expandgrid-content` are inside of a parent container. This will help us think of each preview as a single component. For the example code, I have used `<div name="content-holder">`
- Set `cq-expandgrid-content` as `hidden="true"`, so that by default the iframe is not visible.
- Let the preview thumbnail be responsible for setting the url of the iframe, this will make it easy to play/stop the video when iframe is shown/hidden. Also make sure that you add `autoplay=1` to the end of the src.

  `<div class="cq-expandgrid-toggle" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8SDWdlRzIF8?autoplay=1">`

HTML

```
    <!-- Preview One -->
    <div name="content-holder">
      <div class="cq-expandgrid-toggle" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8SDWdlRzIF8?autoplay=1">Preview 1</div>
      <div name="cq-expandgrid-content" hidden="true">
        <iframe name="pvideo" width="560" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Preview Two -->
    <div name="content-holder">
      <div class="cq-expandgrid-toggle" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eC4Rqa4eQy0?autoplay=1">Preview 2</div>
      <div name="cq-expandgrid-content" hidden="true">
        <iframe name="pvideo" width="560" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Preview Three -->
    <div name="content-holder">
      <div class="cq-expandgrid-toggle" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oUC0FdMLUpQ?autoplay=1">Preview 3</div>
      <div name="cq-expandgrid-content" hidden="true">
        <iframe name="pvideo" width="560" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.cq-expandgrid-toggle').on('click', function(ev) {
    var contentHolder = $(this).parent('div[name=content-holder]');
    var expandGridContent = contentHolder.find("div[name=cq-expandgrid-content]");

    expandGridContent.toggle();
    var iframe = contentHolder.find('iframe');
    if (expandGridContent.is(":visible")) {
      iframe.attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    } else {
      iframe.attr("src", "#");
    }
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
```

This is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/flyinggambit/4zqks7w5/

Comment: Actually I am using #pvideo as iframe id as - `<iframe id="pvideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8SDWdlRzIF8?rel=0" width="560" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>`
which is supposed to be opened when clicked on "cq-expandgrid-toggle". The container that holds the youtube video is cq-expandgrid-content which opens when clicked on cq-expandgrid-toggle. So this might be a different one.

Comment: @user2983808 I updated my answer to work with the new information you gave me. Next time please provide sample HTML code along with your question.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment so that I could rectify my mistakes if any